# In C++ is it more conventional to define method bodies within or outside the class definition?

Tags: c++, methods, convention

Rather self explanatory. I was just wondering what was more conventional to do in object-oriented C++?

Example A:

```
class CarObject{
private:                            //Local Variables
    string name;     
    int cost;
public:
    CarObject(string pName, int pCost){     //Constructor with parameters of car name and car cost
        name = pName;           //Sets the temporary variables to the private variables
        cost = pCost;
    }    
    void getDetails(){ 


            cout << name;
            cout << cost;

            }//Public method that returns details of Car Object
};
```

Example B:

```
class CarObject{
private:                            //Local Variables
    string name;     
    int cost;
public:
    CarObject(string pName, int pCost){     //Constructor with parameters of car name and car cost
        name = pName;           //Sets the temporary variables to the private variables
        cost = pCost;
    }    
    void getDetails();  //Public method that returns details of Car Object
};
void CarObject :: getDetails(){
    cout << name;
    cout << cost;
}
```

Comment: Outside, unless templated.

Comment: Have you ever looked at any C++ code? There are examples all over the internet and in every C++ book and tutorial.

Comment: Does the same apply for constructors?

Comment: Outside unless it is extremely small or template-d. On a secondary note best to use initializer list in your constructors.

Comment: Classes are normally declared in headers. Business logic doesn't belong in headers (but is unavoidable for templates).

Comment: You can jump up and down about principles, but if you write a template then you don't have a choice.  It really needs to go in the header.  You can take a look at your standard C++ library implementation.  It is all in the headers.  SO users are trying to convince you that what's good about everything you *know* is not good for you.  It appears they know something that you don't know. Odd that they can't find the time to really explain it, isn't it?  Very hard to [eradicate that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult), it is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Your class definition will usually be in a .h file, while your methods and other implementation details will be in a .cpp file. This allows for the most flexibility when managing dependencies, prevents unnecessarily recompilation when implementations are changed, and is the pattern that most compilers and IDE's will expect.

The primary exceptions are: (1) `inline` functions, which should be short/simple and which the compiler might choose to insert in place of the actual function call, and (2) templates, the implementations of which depend on the parameters passed to them.